# What is the format for assembler NASM files?

Tags: linux, nasm, assembly

I  want to know what is the format for writing assembler code for NASM. Is there any place which teaches that? I tried to run a MASM32 file on NASM but I think it didn't recognize the instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always [the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html).